# POCO::NET::TCPServer & TCPConnection incoming packet handler?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I can't find it in docs etc.

I want to do request handler like function onPacket() when the new packet come.

Is there possible to do this ?

My currently run function :

```
void run()
{
    Application& app = Application::instance();
    app.logger().information("Request from " + this->socket().peerAddress().toString());
    try
    {
 char  ip[] = "188.xx.xx.xx";
 char port[] = "11001";
        char * data = new char [strlen(ip) + strlen(port) + 13]();
  data[0] = 30;
  data[4] = strlen(ip) + strlen(port) + 4;
  for(int i =0;i<strlen(ip);i++)
  {
   data[8+i] = ip[i];
  }
  data[8 + strlen(ip)] = 0x20;
  for(int i = 0;i<strlen(port);i++)
  {
   data[9 + strlen(ip) + i] = port[i];
  }

        socket().sendBytes(data, strlen(ip) + strlen(port) + 13);
  delete [] data;
    }
    catch (Poco::Exception& exc)
    {
        app.logger().log(exc);
    }
}
```

And i want to do after it packed handler loop.

Comment: You could be looking for something that the [TimeServer example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/TimeServer/src/TimeServer.cpp) illustrates. The question, however, is not very clear. If the above sample does not answer your question, then I suggest you clarify what exactly is it that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I looking for a loop or request handler in run function to handle client incoming packets.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

[Poco::Net Server & Client TCP Connection Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632341/poconet-server-client-tcp-connection-event-handler)

You could use a reactor pattern.

Regards